# MATLAB code, linked to an EXCEL DDE, doesn't pause. What should I do?

Tags: excel, matlab, dde, scada

I'm linking a MATLAB code to a DDE application in Excel.
It works fine, but whenever I try to run the code, the operations are done without respecting pauses each time. This part gets paused in the right way, as it should be:

```
channel = ddeinit('excel','C:\VTScada\NewApplication\Application.xlsx')
%Inserire valori iniziali e finali
s_start = input('s_start','s')
pause(1)
```

When I run the remaning code, like this for example, it's like MATLAB sums all the values of pauses. Then, after some time, it runs all the code in a very rapid way, without respecting pauses each time.

```
ddepoke(channel,'r18c2',1)
pause(10)
ddepoke(channel,'r18c2',0)
ddepoke(channel,'r18c2',1)
pause(10)
ddepoke(channel,'r18c2',0)
```

I tried to solve this problem using the code

```
pause('on')
pause(10)
pause('off')
```

but it turns out that in this particular case, MATLAB doesn't respect pauses at all. It seems to worsen the situation. What should I do?

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes, sorry, the program is Matlab

Comment: Note that MATLAB hasn’t supported the DDE client stuff since version 5.1 (released 1997). You should use the COM model for communication with Excel: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94885-is-the-dde-client-still-supported-by-matlab-7-0-r14

Comment: I know, but in my case it works fine. The only problem is only the one I wrote, Matlab not respecting pauses, and I think I would have the same problem if I switched to the COM model

Comment: Why do you think that? You are using an interface that hasn't been updated with changes to the core MATLAB in about 25 years. I'm not surprised things don't work correctly any more.

Comment: From your description, it seems like MATLAB is doing the `pause`, but the messages are all collected until the MATLAB program finishes, and send out then. I don't know what process MATLAB uses for these messages, but try to add a `drawnow` command after each `pause` statement.

Comment: @CrisLuengo exactly. It's like it collects all the pauses, then doing it all of a sudden. I will try the drawnow command anyway

Comment: @CrisLuengo that could be true. Although I'm having now some problems collecting information about the COM interface

Comment: @CrisLuengo I'd like to try the COM commands. I managed to find how to read from excel. Which commands are for writing to a specific cell? I mean, the equivalent of    `ddepoke`

Comment: @CrisLuengo I tried switching to the COM model, but I have the same problem as before. Communication working, but pauses not getting 'respected'. Plus 'java.lang.Thread.sleep(10 * 1000)'  gets me the same error

Answer (score 1):

The Matlab `pause` command means more than just "wait for N seconds"; it interacts with the graphics pipeline and stuff.

This is a hack, but try doing this instead of `pause`:

```
java.lang.Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
```

That's a lower-level operation that will temporarily stop the program's execution in a more unconditional manner. The `* 1000` is there because `sleep` takes its input in milliseconds instead of seconds.

Comment: It works until the first 50 lines, Then I get the error : One or more output arguments not assigned during call to "java.lang.Thread.sleep"

Comment: Hmm. `java.lang.Thread.sleep` doesn't have any output arguments. Do you maybe have something like `x = java.lang.Thread.sleep(...)` around line 50, that's trying to grab an output argument that isn't there?

Comment: That's all I have before line 50 

if(s_start== '1' && s_end== '2' || s_start == '2' && s_end =='1')
    {    
         
           fprintf('s_start %s, s_end %s', s_start, s_end)
           %Apertura selettori
           ddepoke(channel,'r1c2',0)
           ddepoke(channel,'r2c2',1)
           ddepoke(channel,'r3c2',0)
           ddepoke(channel,'r4c2',1)
          
  %line 50         java.lang.Thread.sleep(10*1000)

Comment: I only give my program's output to Excel, but the problem is that MATLAB refers only to the java.lang.Thread.sleep command, and I don't understand why

Comment: I am trying to use "etime" command from MATLAB. I will see how it works

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem simpling by removing the '{}' after the if, and adding the 'Java.lang.Thread.sleep()' method, instead of the Pause() method.

Thanks to everyone for the help, in any case

Comment: Ah! I don't remember that being in the original code you posted? In Matlab, `{...}` braces don't define blocks for control flow; instead, they construct `cell` arrays, which are a type of value. Might have been screwing up your control flow there.